# Making SSL connection configurable

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2

I want to make SSL connection configurable in my application. The enum System.Net.SecurityProtocolType contains an enum of multiple protocol. If i want to use multiple protocols (say TLS1.2 and SSL3) then how can i do that given i can only set one protocol in my web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at SslProtocols enum. It is flag enum.
So, you can always keep multiple values by keeping bitwise And of all the required protocols